# Make program remember priority in Windows Server R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, process

Is there an elegant way to make a program start with a low priority and remember it?

Answer (score 2):

I would just change the shortcut or create a script that includes the priority as such:

```
start /low notepad.exe
```

Or you could write a script that searches for your specific program and sets its priority, and then schedule the script to run every now and then. Simply select the process you want with a WMI query from [Win32_Process](https://serverfault.com/questions/66059/query-select-from-win32-process-hangs-indefinitely) and use its SetPriority method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the application with a non-default priority.  Generally speaking the only reason to change a process priority is because the process either spikes or uses 100%cpu when another (more important process) needs time.  You should always LOWER priority. Never raise priority above "above normal" unless you understand the process completely and understand the implications of "HIGH PRIORITY" (which in a nutshell can cause your system to appear unresponsive if misused).

To summarize don't do this unless you have a really really good reason to.  If you are coming at this from a unix way of thinking every application is reniced in realtime.

There are 3rd party tools such as [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html) that allow you to save priority settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can also limit it to a number of CPUs which is useful for a piggy process.

`start /low /minimized /afinity 01 notepad.exe`